# Connecting with iPhone

Tags: iphone

Since my recent upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10, the system does not access to iPhone’s ‘My Documents’ folder. Image folder is accessible. I have libimobiledevice installed.

Comment: This worked while you were on 17.04 or 16.04? It might be mounting the device in PTP mode instead of MTP. While your device is mounted try this: `ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/` to see if your device is shown there.

Comment: It worked while I were on 17.04. I tried to type your line in the terminal but it returned nothing at all. One side note: my device is randomly recognized only on one of my 3 USB ports, not always the same. This seems weird.

Comment: When you can get your device to show up, where is it mounted? An easy way to find out would be to go to any folder on your device, and Right Click -> Open in terminal. Then `pwd` should show where the device is mounted.

Comment: /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C024%5D